# Submitting a form without any variable names

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to submit a form to the URL `/search/`, without any variable names.  So that if I input into the form 'foobar', It will then submit the form in GET format to `/search/foobar`.

How can I achieve this?  As far as I can see there is no way to do it with HTML, i'll have to use jQuery.

Comment: Write your server side handler to expect input as standard form encoded data instead.

Comment: if you don't want to send data, why do you need a form? can't you do the same with a link?

Comment: I want to send data, they need to type the search query.

Comment: ok, now I think I understand. You can submit the form with a parameter like `url="foobar"` and let the server redirect you to `/search/{url}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action = "/search/" onsubmit="this.action += encodeURIComponent(this.term.value); this.term.disabled = 'disabled'">
<input type="text" name="term">
</form>
```

Comment: That submits me `search?search=foobar`. I need `/search/foobar`